# ¿Por qué cuando ejecuto este código, no ejecuta la operación, sino que sale [object HTMLInputElement]?

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Por qué cuando ejecuto este código, no calcula el resultado, sino que me muestra [object HTMLInputElement]. Tanto el código comentado como el que no

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="n1"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="n2">
        <button id="pulsa">Calcular</button>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
    </div>
    <script>let boton = document.getElementById("pulsa")
            /*let primerNumero = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
            let segundoNumero = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
            let total = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = n1 + n2

            boton.onclick =function() {
                total
            }*/
            boton.onclick = function () {
                 primerNumero = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
                 segundoNumero = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
                 total = document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = n1 + n2

            }</script>
    <script src="calculadora.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar y explicarme el ¿Por qué ninguno de los dos me sirve?

Comment: ¿Dónde se muestra eso? ¿Te refieres a `total`?  ¿Dónde creas las variabes `n1` y `n2`?

Answer (score 4):

Deberias de sumar las variables `primerNumero` y `segundoNumero` y en vez de no `n1` y `n2`:

```js
let boton = document.getElementById("pulsa")
     
boton.onclick = function () {
     primerNumero = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
     segundoNumero = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
     document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = (primerNumero + segundoNumero)

}
```

```html
 <div>
        <input type="text" id="n1"> <br>
        <input type="text" id="n2">
        <button id="pulsa">Calcular</button>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
    </div>
```

Solo para aclarar, cuando sumas `n1 + n2` que retorna `[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]` es debido a que los elementos html con id estan en el scope global pero no se recomienda que accedeas a ellos directamente del window sino por su id.